# Accessing an app on Remote Desktop does nothing

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, remote-desktop, remote-client

We got users complaining that accessing remote client on Remote Desktop does not bring up anything. When I try logging in to its Azure AVD, it opens up with a black screen and disappears in a second.

A simple start and stop on Azure portal seems to have fixed the problem. A restart did not fix it though. But, I am not sure why it happened in the first place and couldn't find a reason for it. Could anyone offer some suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce same in my environment. I got same error.***

To resolve this issue, try the below.

The reason of this issue is slow sign-in process A black screen will appear for a while, until the regular desktop appears.

When the back screen shows to return to the previous screen, press **CTRL + ALT + END**. This launches ***Task Manager*** you will see the Desktop right away after Task Manager is called like below:

[image]

Make sure to disable the **Bitmap Caching** on the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) client like below.

[image]

Persistent bitmap caching is the combination of memory caching and glyphs. It will be reused throughout client sessions and also provide a bigger amount of cache space, which will result in a black screen.

And try to adjust Display size of your remote host's display like below:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/Yenzbz4.png)]

Now I am able to connect RDP without any issue like below.